# HHVM: pthreads PHP classes

Tags: php, hhvm

The installation of pthreads in PHP (for the use of Threaded, Thread, Worker, Pool, etc) is quite "complex" and that's not very pratical when you use packages of your Linux ditribution that doesn't have ZTS enabled (you have to download PHP sources and compile them — auxiliary question : why ZTS isn't activated by default?).

Few days ago I tested HHVM for the first time and the performance is just... impressive. I'm writing a kind of server in PHP and I need threads. I thought that HHVM support them natively. That's not the case (unknown class).

I can find documentation on pthreads on HHVM documentation, but that's the official PHP docs.
I read somewhere on the Internet that HHVM doesn't support Threads.

So... if threads are supported in HHVM, how to install pthreads on HHVM? What about ZTS?

Comment: ZTS does not provide you with threads you can use in PHP, it just allows you to embed PHP in a threaded program, such as a web server. Also, pthreads is probably very closely tied up with the Zend Engine implementation, so an equivalent for HHVM would probably be written from scratch. I don't know whether it exists, though, so cannot answer your question.

Comment: Oh, also, this typo made me smile: "I read somewhere on the Internet that HHVM doesn't support Internet."

Comment: Ok, thanks, that's what I was thinking. I hope HHVM engineers will work on this. Also, thanks for explaining what ZTS means.
Typo: haha, yes, it made me laugh so hard when I read this x)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ZTS is a prerequisite of pthreads.

ZTS is not used as the default because ZTS mode has some overhead associated with it.

The HHVM documentation is just a clone of the php-doc repository, restyled, with some additional sections added for HHVM, this is why the pthreads documentation shows up in HHVM docs.

HHVM does not and will not support pthreads, or at least, I won't be supporting it, and I wrote pthreads.

HHVM does support concurrency through asynchronous programming, arguably this fits the use case of writing a server better than parallelism: http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/hack.async.php

I have no idea how good that is, the documentation calls it "basic support".

Comment: Thanks! I tried await and async (thanks, I didn't know these features).
I tried that but if you're not using things like SleepWaitHandle (instead of usleep) or GenArrayWaitHandle, the async functions are not async at all. See https://gist.github.com/cburgdorf/9713936 for an example.

Comment: I see the thread extension being supported and loaded when I try get_loaded_extensions, may be I am missing something https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/extensions/introduction

Comment: Sorry I just tried an example and it didn't work, "get_loaded_extensions" in hhvm seems to be misleading.